# Applescript changes?

Tags: applescript

I have a problem with an applescript on an iMac I am upgrading at work, this is below, it stops at:

```
error number -1719 from text field 1 of window 1 of process "QuarkXPress"
```

The full script I am trying to run:

```
try
    tell application "FileMaker Pro Advanced"
        --tell database "artdb_Client"
        set theRecord to current record of database "artdb_Client"

        tell theRecord
            set theCustomer to item 4
            set theCustomerName to item 5
            set theFileName to item 2
        end tell
        --end tell

    end tell


    tell application "QuarkXPress"
        activate
        display dialog ¬
            theCustomer & " - " & theCustomerName default answer theCustomer buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 ¬
            with title "Enter the Customer Code for Job"

        (* 
        display dialog ¬
            theCustomer & " - " & theCustomerName & ¬
            "?" with title "Export PDF for Customer"
        *)
    end tell

    set theFolder to "Data HD:Proofs:" & theCustomer
    set theFolderOfPosix to "/volumes/Data HD/Proofs/" & theCustomer
    set this_item to theFolder & ":" & theFileName & ".pdf"
    set theProofsDir to "Data HD:Proofs:" as alias


    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "QuarkXPress"

            tell menu bar 1
                tell menu bar item "File"
                    tell menu "File"
                        tell menu item "Export"
                            tell menu "Export"
                                click menu item "Layout as PDF..."
                                delay 1
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        repeat 5 times
            tell process "QuarkXPress"
                if window "Export as PDF" exists then

                    keystroke "G" using command down

                    set value of text field 1 of window 1 to theFolderOfPosix & "/"

                    keystroke return
                    click button "Go" of window 1
                    exit repeat
                else
                    delay 1
                end if
            end tell
            delay 1
        end repeat

    end tell
end try
```

Comment: I might add that this script runs fine on an old PowerPC G5, but it doesn't work on a new iMac.

Comment: Yes I have changed that, this is the original script from the old mac.

Comment: No good, although I only understood the first half of what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work, where the script was stopping (without putting the called data in):

set value of text field 1 of window 1 to theFolderOfPosix & "/"

I changed it to:

set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of window 2 to theFolderOfPosix & "/"

Thanks to UI Browser for showing me the "sheet" field I was missing, it doesn't look right but it does the job so that's all that matters I guess.

Comment: This is the major downside of GUI Scripting. You have to rewrite any time the GUI of the target app changes. This can happen even after minor updates, and even when the GUI appears not to have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provision YOUR.app for UI Scripting (Accessibility support) in the Security pane of the System Preferences. There is a good writeup on how that works here: [AppleScript System Notifications Support (advanced)](http://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/notifications/01A.html). That is, it describes the steps necessary to make ui scripting work.
HTH

Comment: It appears I don't have "System Events" in Accessibility.

Comment: Hopefully you know how to find it: I believe it resides in /System/Library/CoreServices. Then you drag it into that pane after you have unlocked the pane. :) You also want to drag Quark Express into the same pane, because your script won't work without it being present there. @Zero: thanks a lot, I have edited my answer slightly.

Comment: The script actually runs from Filemaker, I am trouble shooting the script in applescript as it gives me more feedback of what's going on, I have added Quark to Accessibility, not sure if I was asked about adding Sytem Events, I have been working on this for a few months now in my spare time at work, thanks for all your help, I'll try looking in CoreServices so I can add it.

Comment: You should probably also add Filemaker Pro.

Comment: Yes I added that when I added Quark :)

Comment: Ok I have added System Events to Accessibility and no difference, I have a feeling it's this line of code that's causing the issue: set value of text field 1 of window 1 to theFolderOfPosix & "/" It gets the data but it's unable to put the data in to the correct location.

Comment: In applescript it shows this "set value of text field 1 of window 1 of process "QuarkXPress" to "/volumes/Data HD/Proofs/300056/"" so it's able to get the data, but not able to put that data in to the save field of the window in Quark.

Comment: Hello. I don't have quark, so I can't help you. I take it you have developer tools, so you can use UI Element inspector to double check that you address the correct element?

Comment: No I don't think I have developer tools, is that Xcode ?

Comment: Ok I have downloaded this UI Element Inspector but it doesn't really tell me anything.

Comment: You should really start UI Element inspector, then hoover your mouse over the element in Quark, and then you can lock UI Element Inspector's selection by hitting cmd-F7.

Comment: This is the result when I hover over the area that's it's meant to place the save to location: <AXApplication: “QuarkXPress”>
 <AXWindow: “Export as PDF”>
  <AXSheet>
   <AXTextField>

Attributes:
   AXInsertionPointLineNumber:  “0”
   AXPlaceholderValue:  “(null)”
   AXSelectedTextRange (W):  “pos=4 len=0”
   AXTopLevelUIElement:  “<AXSheet>”
   AXValue (W):  “test”
   AXSelectedText (W):  “”
   AXRoleDescription:  “text field”
   AXHelp:  “(null)”
   AXEnabled:  “1”
   AXParent:  “<AXSheet>”

Comment: Where it says " AXValue (W): “test”" is where I have typed "test" in to the input box.

Comment: It is next to impossible to help you with this, when I don't have Quark express, but, there should be something about UI Scripting out there if you google it, you really have to interpret the attribute names that you get from UI Element inspector, into the correct value for System Events. For instance AXSplitterGroup becomes splitter group 1, and so forth, when you reference the elements via System Events. You should also have a look at the System Events dictionary, but it is only so helpful. Good Luck.